# package code.google.com/p/go.example/hello: exec: "hg": executable file not found in %PATH%. How to get remote golang packages?

Tags: go

I do as written an the Golang tutorial http://golang.org/doc/code.html#remote

My env settings:

```
C:\sbox\go\example>set go
    GOPATH=C:\sbox\go\example
    GOROOT=C:\Go
```

The `example/` folder has only `src/` folder:

```
C:\sbox\go\example\
             |
             --src\
```

Now I call `go get` as described and get an error:

```
C:\sbox\go\example>go get code.google.com/p/go.example/hello
# cd .; hg clone -U https://code.google.com/p/go.example C:\sbox\go\example\src\code.google.com\p\go.example
package code.google.com/p/go.example/hello: exec: "hg": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

After calling `go get`, though, my `example/` folder becomes like this:

```
C:\sbox\go\example\
             |
             --src\
                |
                code.google.com\
                       |
                       --p\
```

And that's all. Nothing more installed.

Then I add a code to my directory structure and it becomes like this:

```
C:\sbox\go\example\
             |
             --src\
                |
                ---code.google.com\
                |        |
                |        --p\
                |
                ---github.com\
                       |
                       --user\
                           |
                           --hello\
                           |   |
                           |   --hello.go
                           |
                           --newmath\
                                |
                                --sqrt.go
```

`hello.go` is like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/user/newmath"
    //"code.google.com/p/go.example/newmath"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, world.  Sqrt(2) = %v\n", newmath.Sqrt(2))
}
```

`sqrt.go` is like this:

```
// Package newmath is a trivial example package.
package newmath

// Sqrt returns an approximation to the square root of x.
func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    z := 0.0
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        z -= (z*z - x) / (2 * x)
    }
    return z
}
```

I just cope/paste them. All as written in the tutorial. Then I do `go install` and run the project. All works fine:

```
C:\sbox\go\example\src\github.com\user\hello>go install

C:\sbox\go\example\bin>hello
Hello, world.  Sqrt(2) = 1.414213562373095
```

Now I again run `go get` and get the same error:

```
C:\sbox\go\example>go get code.google.com/p/go.example/hello
# cd .; hg clone -U https://code.google.com/p/go.example C:\sbox\go\example\src\code.google.com\p\go.example
package code.google.com/p/go.example/hello: exec: "hg": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Ok, I add `bin/` directory to the PATH and run `go get` again but get the same error:

```
C:\sbox\go\example>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\sbox\go\example\bin

C:\sbox\go\example>go get code.google.com/p/go.example/hello
# cd .; hg clone -U https://code.google.com/p/go.example C:\sbox\go\example\src\code.google.com\p\go.example
package code.google.com/p/go.example/hello: exec: "hg": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

What do I need to do get the result as described in the tutorial - remote packages are installed and I can use them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package you are trying to install is under the Mercurial (`hg`) source control system. You need to install [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) to be able to clone the package.